# How to set host_key_checking=false in ansible inventory file?

Tags: ansible

I would like to use `ansible-playbook` command instead of '`vagrant provision`'. However setting `host_key_checking=false` in the `hosts` file does not seem to work.

```
# hosts file
vagrant ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key 
ansible_ssh_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_port=2222 ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 
host_key_checking=false
```

Is there a configuration variable outside of `Vagrantfile` that can override this value?

Answer (score 268, accepted):

<sup>*Due to the fact that I answered this in 2014, I have updated my answer to account for more recent versions of ansible.*</sup>

Yes, you can do it at the host/inventory level (Which became possible on [newer ansible versions](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters)) or global level:

**inventory**:

Add the following.

```
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
```

**host**:

Add the following.

```
ansible_ssh_extra_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
```

hosts/inventory options will work with connection type `ssh` and not `paramiko`. Some people may strongly argue that inventory and hosts is more secure because the scope is more limited.

**global:**

[Ansible User Guide - Host Key Checking](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/connection_details.html#host-key-checking)

- You can do it either in the `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` or `~/.ansible.cfg` file:

  ```
  [defaults]
  host_key_checking = False
  ```
- Or you can setup and env variable (this might not work on newer ansible versions):

  ```
  export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False
  ```

Comment: I'm using ansible 1.7.2 and my experience has been that the environment variable `ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING` works but `-e 'host_key_checking=False'` does not work.

Comment: Your first statement "Yes, but not at the hosts/inventory level" is false. You can use `ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'` or `ansible_ssh_extra_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'`

Comment: Only the last option worked for me (export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False) before running my playbook.

Comment: *"Yes, but not at the hosts/inventory level."* -- Is shown to be false, proven by [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35564773/1254292). I'd even say this is not really an answer to the question on how to set it on *inventory* level.

Comment: @gertvdijk I answered this in 2014.  Ansible has gone through a bunch of revisions. That's not the case anymore ?

Comment: For a oneliner I passed the environment variable in with the command `ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=false ansible all -m ping` it's a shame `ansible -e ansible_host_key_checking=false all -m ping` does not seem to work

Comment: or via ```--ssh-common-args``` command-line option should you wish to rapidly change and debug

Comment: I used ```ansible_ssh_extra_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'``` in inventory vars and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 85):

### Yes, you *can* set this on the inventory/host level.

<sup>*With an already accepted answer present, I think this is a better answer to the question on how to handle this on the inventory level. I consider this more secure by isolating this insecure setting to the hosts required for this (e.g. test systems, local development machines).*</sup>

What you can do at the inventory level is add

```
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
```

or

```
ansible_ssh_extra_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
```

to your host definition (see [Ansible Behavioral Inventory Parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#connecting-to-hosts-behavioral-inventory-parameters)).

This will work provided you use the `ssh` connection type, not `paramiko` or something else).

For example, a Vagrant host definition would look like…

```
vagrant ansible_port=2222 ansible_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
```

or

```
vagrant ansible_port=2222 ansible_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_extra_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
```

Running Ansible will then be successful without changing any environment variable.

```
$ ansible vagrant -i <path/to/hosts/file> -m ping
vagrant | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

In case you want to do this for a group of hosts, here's a suggestion to make it a supplemental group var for an existing group like this:

```
[mytestsystems]
test[01:99].example.tld

[insecuressh:children]
mytestsystems

[insecuressh:vars]
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
```

Comment: This is a much better answer.

Comment: This suggestion worked for me, and I agree that this is something that should be set at a project level (rather than the global level) because of security concerns.

Comment: I included `ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'` in the group_vars file yml file.

Comment: I had a problem when using the server private ip addresses, but then I used the group of hosts configuration, and it worked! You just saved my day, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I could not use:

```
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
```

in inventory file. It seems ansible does not consider this option in my case (ansible 2.0.1.0 from pip in ubuntu 14.04)

I decided to use:

```
server ansible_host=192.168.1.1 ansible_ssh_common_args= '-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null'
```

It helped me.

Also you could set this variable in group instead for each host:

```
[servers_group:vars]
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null'
```

Comment: Setting the `UserKnownHostsFile` / `GlobalKnownHostsFile` option to `/dev/null` also works indeed. It's strange that setting `StrictHostKeyChecking` does not work for you. Most likely is some option in your SSH configuration the cause.

Comment: +1 for `-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null`. Without it also just didn't work for me, irrespective of the the location and way I specified `ansible_ssh_common_args`   outlined in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` uncomment the line:

```
host_key_check = False
```

and in `/etc/ansible/hosts` uncomment the line

```
client_ansible ansible_ssh_host=10.1.1.1 ansible_ssh_user=root ansible_ssh_pass=12345678
```

That's all

Answer (score 0):

Adding following to ansible config worked while using ansible ad-hoc commands:

```
[ssh_connection]
# ssh arguments to use
ssh_args = -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

Ansible Version

```
ansible 2.1.6.0
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
```

Answer (score 0):

You set these configs either in the `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` or `~/.ansible.cfg` or `ansible.cfg`(in your current directory) file

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

**tested with ansible 2.9.6 in ubuntu 20.04**

Answer (score 0):

For people who come here and are using the [`network_cli`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/netcommon/network_cli_connection.html) connection plugin instead of `ssh` and therefore are using either `paramiko` or `libssh` for SSH, you can disable host key checking, if you add this to your host in your inventory:

```
ansible_host_key_checking=false
```

Answer (score 0):

With a new IP address on a DNS name with a new host key, ansible can connect with this in `ansible.cfg`.

```ini
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = '-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o CheckHostIP=no'
```

Mitigates:

- WARNING: POSSIBLE DNS SPOOFING DETECTED!
- WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!