# Ansible - How to ssh into an instance without the 'authenticity of host' prompt?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am using ansible to create several ec2 instances, copy files into those newly created servers and run commands on those servers.  The issue is that after creating the servers I still have to enter yes in the following ssh prompt:

```
TASK [Adding /etc/rc.local2 to consul servers] *********************************
changed: [localhost -> 172.31.52.147] => (item={u'ip': u'172.31.52.147', u'number': 0})
The authenticity of host '172.31.57.20 (172.31.57.20)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 5e:c3:2e:52:10:29:1c:44:6f:d3:ac:10:78:10:01:89.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
changed: [localhost -> 172.31.57.20] => (item={u'ip': u'172.31.57.20', u'number': 1})
The authenticity of host '172.31.57.19 (172.31.57.19)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 4e:71:15:fe:c9:ec:3f:54:65:e8:a1:66:74:92:f4:ff.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

How can I have ansible ignore this prompt and just answer yes automatically?  For reference here is my playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  sudo: yes

  vars_files:
    - ami-keys.yml
    - ami-image.yml    

  tasks:

    - name: create 3 consul servers
      ec2:
         aws_access_key: '{{ aws_access_key }}'
         aws_secret_key: '{{ aws_secret_key }}'
         key_name: terra
         group: default
         instance_type: t2.micro
         image: '{{ ami }}'
         region: '{{ region }}'
         wait: true
         exact_count: 3
         count_tag:
            Name: consul-server
         instance_tags:
            Name: consul-server
      register: ec2


    - name: Wait for SSH to come up
      wait_for: host={{ item }} port=22 delay=1 timeout=480 state=started
      with_items:
        - "{{ ec2['tagged_instances'][0]['private_ip'] }}"
        - "{{ ec2['tagged_instances'][1]['private_ip'] }}"
        - "{{ ec2['tagged_instances'][2]['private_ip'] }}"

    # shows the json data for the instances created
    - name: consul server ec2 instance json data
      debug:
       msg: "{{ ec2['tagged_instances'] }}"

    # bootstrapping
    - name: Adding /etc/rc.local2 to consul servers
      template:
       src: template/{{ item.number }}.sh
       dest: /etc/rc.local2
      delegate_to: "{{ item.ip }}"
      with_items:
        - ip: "{{ ec2['tagged_instances'][0]['private_ip'] }}"
          number: 0
        - ip: "{{ ec2['tagged_instances'][1]['private_ip'] }}"
          number: 1
        - ip: "{{ ec2['tagged_instances'][2]['private_ip'] }}" 
          number: 2
      ignore_errors: true

    - name: give /etc/rc.local2 permissions to run and starting swarm
      shell: "{{ item[1] }}"
      delegate_to: "{{ item[0] }}"
      with_nested:
       - [ "{{ ec2['tagged_instances'][0]['private_ip'] }}", 
           "{{ ec2['tagged_instances'][1]['private_ip'] }}", 
           "{{ ec2['tagged_instances'][2]['private_ip'] }}" ]
       - [ "sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local2",
           "sleep 10",
           "consul reload",
           "docker run --name swarm-manager -d -p 4000:4000 --restart=unless-stopped \
           swarm manage -H :4000 \
           --replication --advertise \
           $(hostname -i):4000 \
           consul://$(hostname -i):8500" ]
      ignore_errors: true
```

**Note:** I have already tried running:

```
ansible-playbook -e 'host_key_checking=False' consul-server.yml
```

and it does not remove the prompt.

Going into `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` and uncommenting the line `host_key_checking=False` does remove the prompt however I want to avoid doing this and either enter something into my playbook or the command line when I run my playbook instead.

Comment: There's a comment on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074412/how-to-set-host-key-checking-false-in-ansible-inventory-file that says the -e "host_key_checking=False" technique did not work and it got 9 up votes, so seems a few people hit this problem.   Can you not just set it it ansible.cfg?

Comment: Editing the `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` file and uncommenting the `host_key_checking=False` line did allow my playbook to run without the prompt.  However I am looking to avoid this step and just be able to disable key checking either inside of my playbook or when I run the playbook on the command line.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The common recommendation is to set `host_key_checking=False` in the Ansible configuration.  This is a bad idea, because it assumes your network connection will never be compromised.

A much better idea that only assumes the network isn't MitMed when you first create the servers is to use `ssh-keyscan` to add the servers' fingerprints to the known hosts file:

```
- name: accept new ssh fingerprints                                         
    shell: ssh-keyscan -H {{ item.public_ip }} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts          
    with_items: '{{ ec2.instances }}'
```

Comment: I tried adding this task to my playbook before my `- name: Adding /etc/rc.local2 to consul servers` task and it completes successfully, but it does not remove the prompt.  I also tried replacing `{{ item.public_ip }}` with `{{ item.private_ip }}` since I am using the internal IP addresses.  I'll do a bit more debugging to see if I can get it working.

Comment: I got it I just had to change `~/.ssh/known_hosts` to `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts` and it works.

Comment: Interesting, are you running ansible as a different user than you're logged in as or something?  Do you know what file it *did* append to?

Comment: Yea I have no idea what it was changing before I specified the known_hosts file of my ubuntu user.  Its not like I did anything special to it.  I made absolutely no changes to the users in my ubuntu 14.04 ec2 instance I am running this playbook on.  I have found that a lot of the time when working in ec2 instances I need to specify the exact path of files and that ~/ will not point to the correct directory.