# Disabling Host key checking on playbook definition

Tags: ansible

Regarding [How to set host_key_checking=false in ansible inventory file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074412/how-to-set-host-key-checking-false-in-ansible-inventory-file) I wanted to know if it is possible to change this setting on the playbook definition.

My playbook is called automatically and I cannot use `export` to set the ENV variable before starting the playbook.

This is what I tried:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  environment:
    ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING: false
  roles:
    - including_vars
```

The problem is that if I add a host during the playbook tasks I get the following error:

> UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Host key verification failed.\r\n", "unreachable": true}

This seems to indicate that the environment variable is not used.

Any idea on how I could change this setting on runtime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set [`ansible_host_key_checking` 
 / `ansible_ssh_host_key_checking`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/f3c3c996422b056a6ba823ceb4ccbb7aab4124dd/lib/ansible/plugins/connection/ssh.py#L27) in the vars section of the play:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    ansible_host_key_checking: false
  roles:
    - including_vars
```

**Important:** when testing with pipelining enabled, give SSH time to expire the persistent connection, otherwise changed settings might not yet be applied.

---

You could also create an in-memory inventory with `host_key_checking` and run your real plays against that inventory (this would also work with Ansible versions older than 2.5):

```
----
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: my_host
        ansible_host: myhost.example.com
        host_key_checking: false

- hosts: my_host
  tasks:
    - ping:
```

Comment: I tried with both proposals but in the end the only thing that worked was `ansible_ssh_extra_args: "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"`

Comment: So you must have done something wrong in your tries.

Comment: there seems to be an open bug on this problem: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/49254

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you have used `env:` instead of `environment:`? e.g.,

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  env:
    ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING: false
  roles:
    - including_vars
```