# ansible run playbook on remote host

Tags: ansible

Could any provide me a better command than below

```
rsync -e "ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l $USER `cat commandResult` "ansible-playbook --connection=local /home/ec2-user/ansible/plays/install.yml"
```

Comment: What about using Ansible the way it was meant to be used, and run `ansible-playbook` on your local host but *target* the remote host?

Comment: @larsks I am executing the above command in Jenkinsfile declarative pipeline

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be much easier to execute the playbook like ansible was intended to work, to get started you can create a file with the host you want to execute the playbook on, for example called 'hosts':

```
[webserver]
web1.hostname.example
```

Then in your playbook you can target this host/host group like so:

```
---
- hosts: webserver
  <<playbook contents here>>
```

Your ansible-playbook command will then look like this:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts /home/ec2-user/ansible/plays/install.yml
```

If you want to ignore host key checking like you are in your `ssh` command, you can do this a number of ways as found in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074412/how-to-set-host-key-checking-false-in-ansible-inventory-file)

Answer (score 0):

```
  ansible-playbook abc/plays/rme/install.yml -u $USER -i `cat commandResult`,
```