# Ansible - How to regenerate a Hosts ssh_host_keys without loosing connection during play

Tags: ansible, ssh-keys

I want to setup freshly imaged Raspberry Pi's with ansible. For this I have tasks to add users, ssh keys and configs. But when I come to the step where I want to regenerate the default ssh_host_*_keys, I lose connection.

I've tried it on 2 ways.
1st by removing all keys and rebooting the host. In this case the host regenerates the keys at boot. All I would have to do is wait, but this doesnt work.

```
- name: SSH | Delete ssh host keys
  file:
    path: '{{ item }}'
    state: absent
  with_items:
    - /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
    - /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
    - /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
    - /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
    - /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
    - /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
    - /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
    - /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
  when: ansible_lsb.id == "Raspbian"
  notify: wait-for-reboot
```

This gives me the following error

```
    TASK [../roles/os : SSH | Delete ssh host keys] *******
ok: [raspi4] => (item=/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key)
changed: [raspi4] => (item=/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key)
changed: [raspi4] => (item=/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub)
fatal: [raspi4]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Connection reset by 192.168.100.12 port 22"}
```

My 2nd try:

```
   - name: SSH | Generate ECDSA Host Key
      openssh_keypair:
        path: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
        owner: root
        state: present
        type: ecdsa
        size: 521
        regenerate: full_idempotence
        force: no
```

The result:

```
TASK [../roles/os : SSH | Generate ECDSA Host Key] ******************************
fatal: [raspi4]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\n@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @\r\n@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\nIT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
```

Edit:
I already have the "host_key_checking = False" in my ansible.cfg. This is needed for the first time connecting to the host. Otherwise I would have to add it to my known_hosts manually by connecting via ssh.

Comment: Your second test is actually successful. Just configure ansible to not verify host key and your are done (or alternatively, remove the local key you automatically registered but that's going to be a challenge since the task makes several connection and your key will change somewhere in the middle of that task...). To disable key checking for ansible, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23094433/9401096)

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, that I already have this in my config set. Otherwise I cant connect for the first time to my pi without adding it to known hosts.