# ping from localhost with delegate_to or local_action not working in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ping, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I am looking execute ping from localhost with delegate_to or local_action, which is not working in Ansible.

Tried with `delegate_to` and also with `local_action`.

```
---
  - name: sampleplaybook
    hosts: all
    become: yes
    become_user: root
    tasks:
     - name: ping check
       #shell: ping -c 1 -w 2 {{ ansible_host }}
       local_action: ping -c 1 -w 2 {{ ansible_host }}
       #delegate_to: localhost
       ignore_errors: true
```

But when I run the playbook, its still looking to establish ssh connection & failing. Anyway to fix it?

> ansible-playbook sample.yml [WARNING]: Invalid characters were found
> in group names but not replaced, use -vvvv to see details
>
> PLAY [sampleplaybook]
>
> ---
>
> TASK [Gathering Facts]
> ************************************************************************************************************************************** The authenticity of host ' (IP#)' can't be established. ECDSA
> key fingerprint is SHA256:............................ ECDSA key
> fingerprint is MD5:........................... Are you sure you want
> to continue connecting (yes/no)? The authenticity of host '
> (IP#)' can't be established.

Comment: The host ansible runs on can't verify the remote host is actually the one your trying to reach. If you trust the connection you can disable strict host checking as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074412/how-to-set-host-key-checking-false-in-ansible-inventory-file

Comment: Ansible's ping is **always** going to make you a SSH connection because it is a Python module run on the target, like any other module, see its synopsis: [_This is NOT ICMP ping, this is just a trivial test module that requires Python on the remote-node_](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ping_module.html#synopsis).

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε , True. Usure if we can disable with option from what @ jshuebel pointed towards. I tried options from the S.O post, but doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @jschuebel , Not sure if it disabled ssh as its highlighted in second link..

Answer (score 0):

While your task will be executed locally either via `delegate_to` or via `local_action`, your play will not. As you did not disable facts gathering, your play will still connect to the hosts to gather facts before executing your task.

Disabling facts gathering should solve your problem:

```yaml
---
- name: sampleplaybook
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: ping check
      ansible.builtin.command: ping -c 1 -w 2 {{ ansible_host }}
      ignore_errors: true
      delegate_to: localhost
```